# Next JS with react Bootsrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Im having issue with my modal need help

I have this component subject which will call my modal component but sadly when I click add new subject the modal wont open but it receives the prop true which should open the modal

subjects.js

```
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import * as React from 'react-bootstrap'
import ModalBox from '../config/modalBox'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useEffect,useState } from 'react'
import './styles/subjects.module.css'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
   faPlus
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

export default function Subject() {


    function handleAddSubject(){
        setAddSubject(true)
    }


    return(
        <Layout>
                
                <div className="add-subject-button">

                <React.Button variant="primary" onClick={handleAddSubject}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus}/>Add Subject</React.Button>
                </div>
                    <ModalBox show={addSubject}/>

        </Layout>
    )
}
```

this is my modal component
modalBox.js

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import * as rbts from 'react-bootstrap'

export default function ModalBox(props) {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(props.show);

    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
      return (
        <rbts.Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
            <rbts.Modal.Header closeButton>
            <rbts.Modal.Title>Modal heading</rbts.Modal.Title>
            </rbts.Modal.Header>
            <rbts.Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</rbts.Modal.Body>
            <rbts.Modal.Footer>
            <rbts.Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                Close
            </rbts.Button>
            <rbts.Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
                Save Changes
            </rbts.Button>
            </rbts.Modal.Footer>
      </rbts.Modal>
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of this line.

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(props.show);
```

You should use the same `props.show` within the modal component (not create another `useState`).

**This should work:**

`subjects.js`

```
<ModalBox show={addSubject} setShow={setAddSubject}/>
```

`modalBox.js`

```
export default function ModalBox(props) {
    const {show, setShow} = props.show;     // Use the same props from the parent component.

    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
      return (
        <rbts.Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
            <rbts.Modal.Header closeButton>
            <rbts.Modal.Title>Modal heading</rbts.Modal.Title>
            </rbts.Modal.Header>
            <rbts.Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</rbts.Modal.Body>
            <rbts.Modal.Footer>
            <rbts.Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                Close
            </rbts.Button>
            <rbts.Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
                Save Changes
            </rbts.Button>
            </rbts.Modal.Footer>
      </rbts.Modal>
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your subject.js you haven't defined the addSubject variable and setAddSubject function